# PHP MYSQL form won't update the database

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a PHP form that displays current data on one side of the page and on the other side are fields that can be filled in to update the data. I have two files "modify.php" and "modify.config.php" to process the update. When hitting the "save" button on modify.php I get a success message (through the config page); the record id (site_id) passes through to the success message in the url but the data does not update in the mysql database. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Modify.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

require_once 'includes/connection.php';

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sites WHERE site_id='$id' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Bad Query: $sql");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

}

?>

<form action='modify.config.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>' method='POST'>        

<table width='100%'>
<thead>
<th colspan='2'><strong>Current Details:</strong></th>
<th colspan='2' style='background-color:#2c9cd4; color:#ffffff;'><strong>New Details:</strong></th>
</thead>  
<tr class='hover'>
<td width='15%'><strong>Site Code: </strong></td>
<td width='35%'><?php echo $row['site_code'] ?></td>
<td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f2f2f2'><input type='text' name='site_code' class='input2' placeholder='Site Code (UCCE)' maxlength='4' size='20' id='site_code' value='<?php if (isset($trimmed['site_code'])) echo $trimmed['site_code']; ?>' autofocus /></td>
</tr>
</tr>
<tr class='hover'>
<td width='15%'><strong>Name: </strong></td>
<td width='35%'><?php echo $row['site_name'] ?></td>
<td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f2f2f2'><input type='text' name='site_name' class='input2' placeholder='Site Name' maxlength='100' size='50' id='site_name' value='<?php if (isset($trimmed['site_name'])) echo $trimmed['site_name']; ?>' autofocus /></td>
</tr>
<tr class='hover'>
<td width='15%'><strong>Description: </strong></td>
<td width='35%'><?php echo $row['description'] ?></td>
<td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f2f2f2'><input type='text' name='description' class='input2' placeholder='Description' maxlength='100' size='50' id='description' value='<?php if (isset($trimmed['description'])) echo $trimmed['description']; ?>' autofocus /></td>
</tr>
<tr class='hover'>
<td width='15%'><strong>Street Address: </strong></td>
<td width='35%'><?php echo $row['address_street'] ?></td>
<td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f2f2f2'><input type='text' name='address_street' class='input2' placeholder='Street Address' maxlength='100' size='50' id='address_street' value='<?php if (isset($trimmed['address_street'])) echo $trimmed['address_street']; ?>' autofocus /></td>
</tr>
<tr class='hover'>
<td width='15%'><strong>City: </strong></td>
<td width='35%'><?php echo $row['address_city'] ?></td>
<td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f2f2f2'><input type='text' name='address_city' class='input2' placeholder='City' maxlength='100' size='50' id='address_city' value='<?php if (isset($trimmed['address_city'])) echo $trimmed['address_city']; ?>' autofocus /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<span style='float:right;'>
<button type='submit' class='save' id='submit' name='submit'>
<img src='images/save.png' height='13px' width='13px' style='vertical-align: sub;' />  Save </button>
<input type='hidden' name='submit' id='submit' value='TRUE' />
</span>
</form>
```

And Modify.Config.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {

require_once 'includes/connection.php';

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sites WHERE site_id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Bad Query: $sql");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

}

include 'includes/connection.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$site_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['site_code']));
$site_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['site_name']));
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['description']));
$address_street=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['address_street']));
$address_city = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['address_city']));

$error = false;

if (!$error) {
if (!empty($site_code) && !empty($site_name) && !empty($description) && !empty($address_street) && !empty($address_city))

{

$sql = "UPDATE sites SET site_code='$site_code', site_name='$site_name', description='$description', address_street='$address_street', address_city='$address_city' WHERE site_id='$id'";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

}

$page_title = "Modify Success";
$page_content = "Site <strong><a href='site.php?id={$row['site_id']}'> {$row['site_code']} {$row['description']}</a></strong> has been successfully modified.";
include "header.php";
include "includes/box_success.php"; 
echo "<p>&nbsp;<p>";
include "footer.php";

mysqli_close($conn);

exit();

} else {

$page_title="Modify - ERROR";
$page_content = "<p><strong>The site {$row['site_code']} could not be updated.</strong></p><p>{$sql}<br>{mysqli_error($conn)}</p>";
include "header.php";
include "includes/box_error.php";
echo "<p valign='middle'>
<span style='float:left'>
<a href='modify.php?id={$row['site_id']}'>
<button type='submit' class='trans-left' value='submit-previous'>
<img src='images/chevron_back.png' height='15' width='18' style='vertical-align: sub;' />
Retry 
</button></a>
</span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>";
echo "</div>";
include "footer.php";

}

} 

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Have you ever thought about using a form validator like JQuery Validate to handle your forms?

Comment: Where are your `$trimmed` values that are in your inputs being populated at?

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE sites SET site_code=$site_code, site_name=$site_name, description=$description, address_street=$address_street, address_city=$address_city WHERE site_id=$id";

Comment: Try changing to above you are using single quotes inside of double remove the single quote to pass the variable. If you use single quote it will treat as string not variable

Comment: I removed the $trimmed values and replaced them with htmlsentities on modify.php. Still no luck though.    <td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f2f2f2'><input type='text' name='site_name' class='input2' placeholder='Site Name' maxlength='100' size='50' id='site_name' value='<?php htmlentities($row['site_name']); ?>' autofocus /></td>

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are committing the changes to the database? I see you doing an update then closing the connection. Try adding the following before you close the connection.

```
mysqli_commit($conn);
```

Comment: I removed the single quotes as suggested and no luck. I also changed "mysqli_close($conn);" to "mysqli_commit($conn);" and still no luck.

Comment: Have you verified all the values are not empty as how you have it coded if any of the values are empty it bypasses the actual update?